# Как посмотреть расположение полей структуры c/c++ в памяти?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Допустим хочу посмотреть расположение полей до упаковки структуры

```
//sizeof(test) == 8
struct test {
    int i;
    char c;
};
```

и после

```
//sizeof(test) == 5 (g++)
pragma pack(push,1)
struct test {
    int i;
    char c;
};
pragma pack(pop)
```

Как это делается?

Comment: Ну вроде как предполагается, что программист способен представить это в уме.

Comment: Создайте переменную данного типа, заполните поля данными, чтобы их легче было идентифицировать, остановитесь на брекпоинте и откройте дамп памяти по адресу, где расположена ваша переменная. При пошаговой отладке в дебагере вы также можете наблюдать как изменяются значения байт памяти при изменении значений переменных.

Comment: Компилятор укажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смещения полей в структуре вам даст стандартное макро `offsetof` (`<stddef.h>`, `<cstddef>`)

```
size_t 
  offset_i = offsetof(struct test, i),
  offset_c = offsetof(struct test, c);
```

а размеры полей и самой структуры вы получите через `sizeof`. Это даст вам полную картину расположения полей внутри структуры.